# Is gold cost a prerequisite (+5 to DC) for crafting magic items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

From what I understand, the only thing that is completely, 100% required to craft an item is having the feat to do so. Everything else is a prerequisite that, if you do not have it, adds +5 to the DC of the Spellcraft check.

Does this mean that the *gold cost* is also a prerequisite?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Note that you also cannot forgo prerequisites for potions and spell completion/spell trigger items (scrolls, wands, and staves).

Answer (score 8):

### No

Gold is a *cost* (specifically, the cost to buy the materials needed to physically make the item).

Requirements are features that the crafter(s) 'need' to meet to work those materials.

You can note the difference in the Construction portion of any magic item (here, from a [Belt of Tumbling](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Belt%20of%20Tumbling))

> **Requirements** Craft Wondrous Item, cat’s grace; **Cost** 400 gp

The different 'types' of construction demands are bolded (Requirements and Cost) and separated by a semicolon.

From [Creating Wondrous Items](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Creating%20Wondrous%20Items&Category=Magic%20Item%20Creation),

> To create a wondrous item, a character usually needs some sort of equipment or tools to work on the item. She also needs a supply of materials, the most obvious being the item itself or the pieces of the item to be assembled. **The cost for the materials is subsumed in the cost for creating the item.** Wondrous item costs are difficult to determine. Refer to Table 15–29 and use the item prices in the item descriptions as a guideline. **Creating an item costs half the market value listed.**